# How to send variable along with Redirect in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following in my react app:

```
<PrivateRoute 
  path="/profile" 
  component={ Profile }
  authenticated={ this.state.authenticated }
```

/>

`<PrivateRoute/>` is basically just the below:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component : Component , authenticated : auth , ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={ (props) => {
      return (
        auth ? <Component {...props} /> 
        : <Redirect 
            to={{
                pathname : '/login',
                state : {
                    from : props.location
                }
            }} />
      )
    } } />
  )
}
```

As you can see in the above code there is a `auth` variable , how do i send this variable to now i would like to send this variable alog with the `<Redirect />` which basically loads the `<Login />` component , but how exactly do i send the auth variable alog with the Redirect component ?

Comment: Like you are sending location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass props data with `Redirect` like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component : Component , authenticated : auth , ...rest }) => {
return (
<Route {...rest} render={ (props) => {
  return (
    auth ? <Component {...props} /> 
    : <Redirect 
        to={{
            pathname : '/login',
            state : {
                from : {auth : auth}
            }
        }} />
  )
} } />
```

)
}

and this is how you can access it:

```
this.props.location.state.auth
```

Comment: I guess it should be `state: {
from: props.location, 
auth: auth
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this.props.history.push and access that variable by this.props.location